# 2 GAM Sponsorship line items never rotate despite sharing a unit. The second only appears in it's second slot the first only has one slot

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

In Google Ad Manager we have 2 orders with line item type "sponsorship": Ad 1 and Ad 2

Ad 1 has Position A; custom targeting page ID = 123
Ad 2 has Position A + Position B; custom targeting page ID = 123 + custom targeting tags = "foo" "bar"

Page ID 123 doesn't send tags at all, just the ID = 123.

On Page ID 123:
Ad 1 is only ever in position A
Ad 2 is only ever in position B
They never rotate

On other pages with tags "foo", "bar" but not ID = 123:
Ad 2 appears in position A
Ad 1 doesn't appear

This all works exactly as we want, but we don't understand how.
We've refreshed this page dozens of times on different days and it never changes.

I expected we would need to set up a different line item to get Ad 2 to appear in position A because it would interfere with the targeting ID = 123 and rotate. But we tried it anyway and it works. But how? Can I trust this?

Comment: It all depends on your custom targetings : page ID AND foo=bar ? page ID OR foo=bar ?